# Modules with first Betti number bigger than the second Betti number

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian local ring (with 1) and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Consider a minimal free presentation of $M$ as follows: $R^{\beta_2}\rightarrow R^{\beta_1}\rightarrow M\rightarrow0$. Is there a nice characterization of modules with $\beta_1>\beta_2$? What are these modules?

I had naively thought perhaps they are modules with annihilator equal to zero, but that's not true as you can see in a previous question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68956/presentation-of-finite-modules-with-null-annihilator).

Comment: Perhaps this question is too general to have a definite answer.

Comment: Well, what kind of characterization you are hoping for? 

Comment: Anything that is special about these modules could be interesting. What are some conditions (if any) that are equivalent to having $\beta_1>\beta_2$? 

Comment: Do you know what kind of rings is $R$? 

Comment: $R$ is arbitrary, but if it is necessary to have extra assumptions for some equivalent conditions, you can add those assumptions. 